# How to make left and right arrow in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a screenshot as shown below which I have to replicate in HTML/CSS. In the following screenshot I wasn't able to make **colored left and right arrows** in between the squares. 
[image]

At this moment, I am able to replicate this in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nepgqcjL/1/embedded/result/) **without colored left and right arrows**.

The snippets of CSS code which I have used in order to make series of small squares are:

```
.squares .square {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what CSS codes I should add in the fiddle so that **colored left and right arrows** **in between the squares** shows up in the fiddle.

Comment: Could you share your markup?

Comment: @SydneyKhanye Markup ?

Comment: Yes, a snippet of your html code.

Comment: @SydneyKhanye All HTML and CSS codes are already in the fiddle.

Comment: @user5447339 thats not how stack overflow works, you need to post your relevant code in the question, the reason why people dont like having links to other places is, those links may be deleted in the future and then this question is useless to help others in the future - reviewing your post history you are not new to stack overflow so you should know this...

Comment: @JuvenileSnow The relevant codes I have pasted in the question regarding what HTML and CSS codes I have use in order to make a square. Regarding left and right colored arrows, I am not sure how to make it that's why I didn't mention in the question.

Comment: @user5447339 depending on your use case there are a million ways you could do this.. could you be more specific? does it need to responsive? can they just be images of arrows?

Comment: My mistake, I'll check it out.

Comment: I am focused on the desktop design at this moment but will definitely see later what I want for mobile/tablet design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by HTML special characters like below:

```css
.squares {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.squares .square {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.squares .square p
{
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}
.arrows {
 text-align:center;
}
.arrows span {
 display:block;
 font-size:48px;
 line-height:32px;
 color:green;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.arrows span:first-child {
 color:#C90;
}
```

```html
<div class="squares">
    <div class="square"><p>Franchise Hub Hierarchy</p><img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/jvu89zp17/Layer_30.png" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="arrows">
        <span>&rarr;</span>
        <span>&larr;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="square"><p>System wide user permissions</p><img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/6ronxc7a3/Layer_33.png" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="arrows">
        <span>&rarr;</span>
        <span>&larr;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="square"><p>Custom Corporate Branding</p><img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/wn8egkbor/Layer_46.png" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="arrows">
        <span>&rarr;</span>
        <span>&larr;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="square"><p>Configurable Workflow</p><img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/k8lmg8rwb/Layer_47.png" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="arrows">
        <span>&rarr;</span>
        <span>&larr;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="square"><p>Orders, C.R.M. and P.O.S</p><img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/9yj7h0hgb/Shape_33.png" alt=""/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try font awesome arrows
https://fontawesome.com/icons/arrow-left?style=solid

or make arrows using `CSS borders`

```css
#arrow {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 20px solid transparent;
 border-left: 40px solid red;
 border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
 margin-left:  20px;
  }
  
#arrow:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px ;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  left: 0;
  top: 22px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="arrow"></div>
```

and if you want your text towards the bottom of your box, You should write `<p>` after `<img>`.

```
<div class="square">    
    <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/jvu89zp17/Layer_30.png" alt=""/>
    <p>Franchise Hub Hierarchy</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the cure CSS and simplest solution for your problem.
I have done this for you, just add a div between every square div

```
<div class="arrowWrapper">
  <span class="arrow redArrow"></span><br>
  <span class="arrow greenArrow"></span>
</div>
```

and this css to your code:

```
.arrow {
  display:block;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  width: 35px;
  position: relative;
}
.arrow.redArrow {background-color: red;}
.arrow.greenArrow {background-color: green;}
.arrowWrapper { margin-right: -20px; margin-left: -20px;}
.arrow.redArrow:after{
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 height: 2px;
 width: 12px;
 background: red;
 right: -1px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 top: -4px;
}
.arrow.redArrow:before{
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 2px;
width: 12px;
background: red;
right: -1px;
transform: rotate(135deg);
top: 4px;
}
.arrow.greenArrow:after{
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 2px;
width: 12px;
background: green;
left: -1px;
transform: rotate(135deg);
top: -4px;
}
.arrow.greenArrow:before{
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 2px;
width: 12px;
background: green;
left: -1px;
transform: rotate(45deg);
top: 4px;
}
```

Complete code is in below snippet
enjoy

```css
.squares {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items:center;
padding: 1rem;
background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.squares .square {
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
height: 200px;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 15px;
}

.squares .square p
{
text-align: center;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
.arrow {
display:block;
height: 2px;
margin: 3px 0;
width: 35px;
position: relative;
}
.arrow.redArrow {background-color: red;}
.arrow.greenArrow {background-color: green;}
.arrowWrapper { margin-right: -20px; margin-left: -20px;}
.arrow.redArrow:after{
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 2px;
width: 12px;
background: red;
right: -1px;
transform: rotate(45deg);
top: -4px;
}
.arrow.redArrow:before{
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 2px;
width: 12px;
background: red;
right: -1px;
transform: rotate(135deg);
top: 4px;
}
.arrow.greenArrow:after{
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 2px;
width: 12px;
background: green;
left: -1px;
transform: rotate(135deg);
top: -4px;
}
.arrow.greenArrow:before{
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 2px;
width: 12px;
background: green;
left: -1px;
transform: rotate(45deg);
top: 4px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="squares">
    <div class="square"><p>Franchise Hub Hierarchy</p><img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/jvu89zp17/Layer_30.png" alt=""/></div>
<div class="arrowWrapper">
    
    
    <span class="arrow redArrow"></span><br>
    <span class="arrow greenArrow"></span></div>
    <div class="square"><p>System wide user permissions</p><img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/6ronxc7a3/Layer_33.png" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="square"><p>Custom Corporate Branding</p><img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/wn8egkbor/Layer_46.png" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="square"><p>Configurable Workflow</p><img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/k8lmg8rwb/Layer_47.png" alt=""/></div>
 <div class="square"><p>Orders, C.R.M. and P.O.S</p><img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/9yj7h0hgb/Shape_33.png" alt=""/></div>
</div>
```